# Lombok not compatible with IntelliJ 2021.1.2

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-lombok-plugin

Was about to update my intelliJ, and it states lombok is not compatible. Anyone else have any issues with updating?

Comment: Could you please clarify the issue? Do you try to install Lombok plugin? Since 2021 it's bundled in IDE.

Comment: @y.bedrov hi, i was about to update my intelliJ and then a warning came up, all my projects use lombok. Hence why i was asking..

Comment: Could you please share your idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?